# Appcenter Could not determine API level for $(TargetFrameworkVersion) of 'v11.0'

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

it builds on my local machine but throws this error in microsoft appcenter when building.

Its a xamarin.android project using androidx libraries

Comment: Check your `Target Framework version` and the `SDK version` (when you build in appcenter),are they all `Android11` ?